# Xaml Exception when add image to RibbonButton

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**Exception:** "An exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll but was not handled in user code.

Additional information: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '22' and line position '40'.
"

**Have Tried:**

- Set Build Action of image to Resource
- Turned on first chance exceptions
- Running without an image on the button
- adding to front `pack://application:,,,`

When I run the project without an image, everything loads just fine.

the namespace of this project `Ribbon.Views`

**Xaml:**

```
<Ribbon>
    <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
        <RibbonApplicationMenu Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
    <Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
        <RibbonQuickAccessToolBar Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
    <RibbonTab>
        <RibbonTab.Header>
            <RibbonTabHeader Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        </RibbonTab.Header>
        <RibbonGroup>
            <RibbonButton Label="Main"
                          LargeImageSource="/imgs\FileIcon.png"
                               >
            </RibbonButton>
        </RibbonGroup>
    </RibbonTab>
</Ribbon>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write address like that:

```
<RibbonButton Label="Main" LargeImageSource="..\imgs\FileIcon.png"></RibbonButton>
```

Comment: that gives me same exception.

Comment: yes it does, when I move the folder inside the views folder it works. but when it is in the root it doesn't. That was the reason for the "/".

Comment: yes and its "namespace" is YourApplication.imgs.FileIcon.png

Comment: @JamTay317 I've updated my code. Try this code, please

Comment: I really do not know, I just have assumption that If your .xaml file is in a different folder, then you need towrite like that "../Img/fileicon.png"